# Найти координаты для каждого уникального элемента в матрице

Tags: python, массивы, циклы, матрицы

```
tab1 = [[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
        [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
        [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
        [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
        [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
        [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9],
        [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9],
        [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9]]

for row in tab1:
    print(' '.join([str(elem) for elem in row]))

tab1p = [[0]*9 for i in  range(0,9)]

for i in range(0,9):
    for j in range(0,9):
        for k in range(1,10):
            if tab1[i][j] == k:
                tab1p[k-1][j] = [i, j]

for row in tab1p:
    print(' '.join([str(elem) for elem in row]))
```

Получаю

```
[2, 0] [2, 1] [2, 2] 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 [2, 3] [2, 4] [2, 5] 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 [2, 6] [2, 7] [2, 8]

[5, 0] [5, 1] [5, 2] 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 [5, 3] [5, 4] [5, 5] 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 [5, 6] [5, 7] [5, 8]

[8, 0] [8, 1] [8, 2] 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 [8, 3] [8, 4] [8, 5] 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 [8, 6] [8, 7] [8, 8]
```

Хочу получить массив с "координатами" равных элементов:

- `[[[0,0][0,1][0,2][1,0][1,1][1,2][2,0][2,1][2,2]]`(координаты элементов равных 1)
- `[[0,3][0,4][0,5][1,3][1,4][1,5][2,3][2,4][2,5]]` (координаты элементов равных 2)
- `[[0,6][0,7][0,8][1,6][1,7][1,8][2,6][2,7][2,8]]` (координаты элементов равных 3) и так далее

Comment: вы можете привести в вопросе пример матрицы (списка), которую вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: Сейчас поправлю

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите получить координаты для каждого уникального элемента?

Comment: Да, и совместить координаты для равных в одном подсписке

Comment: по поводу совместить я не понял. Можете указать __весь__ (все строки) результат, который вы хотите получить? Иначе не очень понятно...

Comment: Весь долго писать, но я исправил до первых трех, надеюсь теперь понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

coords = defaultdict(list)
for i, row in enumerate(tab1):
    for j, x in enumerate(row):
        coords[x].append((i, j))
```

Результат:

```
{1: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)],
 2: [(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)],
 3: [(0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8)],
 4: [(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2)],
 5: [(3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5)],
 6: [(3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8)],
 7: [(6, 0), (6, 1), (6, 2), (7, 0), (7, 1), (7, 2), (8, 0), (8, 1), (8, 2)],
 8: [(6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (7, 3), (7, 4), (7, 5), (8, 3), (8, 4), (8, 5)],
 9: [(6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (8, 6), (8, 7), (8, 8)]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы воспользовался модулем Numpy в данном случае:

```
In [84]: import numpy as np

In [85]: a = np.array(tab1)

In [86]: a
Out[86]:
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9],
       [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9],
       [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9]])

In [87]: res = {x:list(zip(*np.where(a==x))) for x in np.unique(a.ravel())}

In [88]: res
Out[88]:
{1: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)],
 2: [(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)],
 3: [(0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8)],
 4: [(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2)],
 5: [(3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5)],
 6: [(3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8)],
 7: [(6, 0), (6, 1), (6, 2), (7, 0), (7, 1), (7, 2), (8, 0), (8, 1), (8, 2)],
 8: [(6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (7, 3), (7, 4), (7, 5), (8, 3), (8, 4), (8, 5)],
 9: [(6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (8, 6), (8, 7), (8, 8)]}
```

Comment: А он будет работать с цифрами в другом порядке?

Comment: Можно решение без numpy, т.к. нет у меня такого модуля? Да и для моего уровня очень не понятно

Comment: @Эльдар, мне надо убегать, но я думаю вам сейчас и так набросают ответов без Numpy... ;-)